# How to execute Shell Script from Flask App

Tags: python, bash, shell, flask

I've created and deployed a Flask App with Apache2 server WSGI in which now would like to run a .sh script from the App.  However, from calling from python code, it doesn't execute.

Here is the test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi from shell script"
```

Here is my python flask app code index.py (runs when App is opened) but nothing is printed or executed:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/scripts/test.sh')
```

To check that there is not errors in my code, I've check flask error logs, and no errors.  Also, I created a script called test_shell_script.py with same python code as above (but not flask app code) and it runs great like this:

```
# test_shell_script.py
import subprocess
subprocess.call('/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/scripts/test.sh')
```

And then run it with python:
    python3 /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/test_shell_script.py

```
hi from shell script
```

I did change the permissions as well:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 364 Nov 19 17:48 ../scripts/test.sh
```

What am I missing here which is not allowing my Flask app to run shell commands from the python code?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? This looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python, can you try the `subprocess.Popen` suggestion?

Comment: Receive no error.  I've tried subprocess.Popen and even os.system

Comment: You gave permission to root for the file `run_sql.sh` but the file name you are trying to run is `test.sh`

Comment: @Seraf - sorry that was a typo, fixed it now

Comment: Weird, the user that runs the Flask app is root? (Probably yes but still asking)

Comment: @Seraf - yes it's root

Comment: I just ran a simple flask app and I'm calling the api endpoint, I see `hi from shell script` on my terminal on the `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/` can you show me the API endpoint code you are trying to call? I also took permission with `chmod 777`. Also if nothing executes it might be just a typo in the route? Can you make the endpoint return something so you're sure that it's called

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To show command output inside Python, there are two popular methods:

1. `check_output()`: It runs command with arguments and return its output. [(official documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)
2. `subprocess.communicate()`: Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. [(official documentation)](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

I could view the shell file output using both methods using *Python 3.5* in an *Ubuntu* machine.

`app.py`:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from subprocess import check_output
from flask import Flask

def get_shell_script_output_using_communicate():
    session = Popen(['./some.sh'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = session.communicate()
    if stderr:
        raise Exception("Error "+str(stderr))
    return stdout.decode('utf-8')

def get_shell_script_output_using_check_output():
    stdout = check_output(['./some.sh']).decode('utf-8')
    return stdout

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET',])
def home():
    return '<pre>'+get_shell_script_output_using_check_output()+'</pre>'

app.run(debug=True)
```

`some.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi from shell script"
echo "hello from shell script"
```

Output screenshot:

[image]

Comment: In `get_shell_script_output_using_communicate()` stderr also needs to be decoded using `raise Exception("Error "+str(stderr.decode('utf-8')))`